# Android chat app keeps on crashing when I run it

Tags: java, android

I have just begun writing some code for my Chat app after days of planning but the problem is that keeps on crashing right after the Gradle Build has finished and the app is installed on my device. I have created a button that is expected to open a new activity but instead of doing so it crashes. Everything works before I have written any code, the app opens and logcat doesn't show any errors. Here is the error:

```
2022-08-10 19:26:48.372 15348-15348/? E/e.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
2022-08-10 19:26:48.391 15348-15348/? E/RefClass: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2022-08-10 19:26:48.474 15348-15348/com.example.myapplication E/Perf:  perftest packageName : com.example.myapplication App is allowed to use Hide APIs  
2022-08-10 19:26:48.515 15348-15374/com.example.myapplication E/libEGL: Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
2022-08-10 19:26:48.528 15348-15348/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15348
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3628)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3887)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:263)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:183)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:744)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:848)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:12)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3616)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3887) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2317) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:263) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8292) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
```

I tried following some other suggestions but they didn't work. Here's the snippet of my code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button signUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `findViewById()` outside of `onCreate()` like this and if you really wanna do that, do it by creating a new method for setting up IDs and then add that method in `onCreate()`.

this code will do the work now:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    public Button signUp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        signUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity();
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void openActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working...

Comment: what's the error say now, and provide updated code too.